# AmCharts remove gap at start of serialChart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying AmCharts for the first time and having trouble with one small thing. I created a graph using the following javascript:

```
   dayGraph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
   dayGraph.valueField = "value";
   dayGraph.type = "line";
   dayGraph.balloonText = "<b>[[value]]</b>";
   dayGraph.connect = false;
   dayGraph.lineThickness = 2;
   dayGraph.lineColor = "#8B0000";
   dayGraph.fillColor = "#8B0000";
   dayGraph.fillAlphas = 0.5;

   chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();

   energyChart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
   energyChart.categoryField = "time";
/*   energyChart.startDuration = 1;*/
   energyChart.addGraph(dayGraph);
   energyChart.categoryAxis.parseDates = true;
   energyChart.categoryAxis.minPeriod = "mm";
   energyChart.chartCursor = chartCursor;
   energyChart.categoryAxis.equalSpacing = true;
```

It seems to work well, but I can't seem to find a way to remove the gap at the start of the graph (before the 00:00 value). The first data point is exactly at 00:00, so I would expect this point to sit on the vertical axis. Instead, there is a small gap. See the images below for how it currently is, and how I want it to look.

The current graph looks like this:

[image: Current]

I want it to look like this:

[image: Desired]

Comment: When you say "there is no data from 00:00 to about 00:08" do you mean you have data points for those minutes, just no values for them? If that is so, you will need to remove data points as well so they're not there. The chart will show date/time scale for all existing data points regardless if they contain any values or not.

Comment: There is "null" from 00:00 to 00:08, and I want that period to be shown. My issue is the gap before 00:00. I would like the graph to start exactly at the vertical axis. I've attached different (better) image which doesn't have any missing data if that helps

Comment: After a bit more looking around, it seems that that initial gap is there for "column" and "step" graphs. It makes sense for those types of graphs, where each data point has a 'width', however I think it should be able to be removed for 'line' graphs, since there should be no 'width' for each point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each serial chart already has `categoryAxis` property with a reference to `CategoryAxis` object. So you can just set it's `startOnAxis` property to `true`:

```
energyChart.categoryAxis.startOnAxis = true;
```

or, if you need to instantiate your own:

```
energyChart.categoryAxis = new AmCharts.CategoryAxis();
energyChart.categoryAxis.startOnAxis = true;
```

Whatever floats your boat.

Also, it's worth noting, that for date-based category axes, `startOnAxis` will work only if `equalSpacing` is set to `true`.

Comment: hmmmmm.... I tried setting the startOnAxis previously and it did nothing, but just tried it now and worked perfectly. The 'gridPosition' isn't necessary for me, it works without it.

Comment: Glad it worked this time for you. Also, you're right about gridPosition. I just looked at the documentation again and "end" isn't even a valid value - it defaults to "middle" which is the correct setting. I'll edit to remove the erroneous value.

Comment: @J.Titus I edited your answer. In object-based amCharts approach, where an instance of the class is required, you can't assign just the generic object, like `{}`, you need to instantiate an object of the class, i.e. `new AmCharts.CategoryAxis()`.

Comment: @J.Titus you saved my day! I spend lot of time looking for that feature! Thanks